# Рекурсивно заполнить бинарное дерево. Python

Tags: python, data-structures

Есть функция, рекурсивно делящая массив на две части, пока каждая длина каждой части не будет меньше 10. Как сделать так, чтобы эта функция возвращала мне бинарное дерево, корнем которого был бы изначальный массив, а следующих узлах лежали бы результаты деления каждого вызова (подмассивы). Желательно, чтобы было удобно до этих данных добираться

Пример:

```
[1..20] -- [1..5]
  |
[6, 20] -- [6,11]
  |
[12,20]
```

Ниже программа:

```
data = [i for i in range(50)]
def func(data, max_len=10):

    r = random.randint(0, len(data))

    data1 = data[:r]
    data2 = data[r:]

    if len(data1) < max_len and len(data2) < max_len:
        print(len(data2), len(data1))
        print('DONE!')

    elif len(data1) < max_len:
        func(data=data2)
        print(len(data2), len(data1))
    elif len(data2) < max_len:
        func(data=data1)
        print(len(data2), len(data1))
    else:
        func(data=data2)
        func(data=data1)
        print(len(data2), len(data1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
data = [i for i in range(50)]
mass = [0] * 2**10
def func(data, max_len=10, k=1):

    if len(data) < max_len:
        mass[k-1] = data
        return

    r = random.randint(0, len(data)-1)

    data1 = data[:r]
    data2 = data[r:]

    mass[k-1] = data

    func(data=data2, k=2*k + 1)
    func(data=data1, k=2*k)
    print(len(data2), len(data1))
```